# Bootstrap 3: some Videos not filled to parent Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a grid of videos that I want to display side by side and hence padding & margin is both set to 0 using Bootstrap.

Initially before the video loads, the videos fill the parent div completely but when it plays, some videos become smaller so there are white gaps in the div which I do not want.

It seems it's not obeying the css rules or that it could be an video aspect problem which I have no idea how to fix.

JSFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ypbbb522/) of the problem.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" >
        <video class="embed-responsive-item" autoplay loop poster="http://thumbs.gfycat.com/<%= title %>-thumb360.jpg">     
                <source src=<%= gif.webmurl %> type="video/webm">
                <source src=<%= gif.mp4url %> type="video/mp4">
        </video>  
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you post a working fiddle (not `.NET`) version. It will easy to us to help you.

Comment: The fiddle works for me, how do I post a JSFiddle that's not a .NET version?

Comment: Probably is different aspect ratio. Try to force width or heigt inside video tag like this: `<video style="width:640px;height:360px;" class="embed-responsive-item" autoplay loop poster="http://thumbs.gfycat.com/<%= title %>-thumb360.jpg">`

Comment: Still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all the videos have same format and same quality.

If video quality changes video player takes the place accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the white space by setting the .embed-responsive .embed-responsive-16by9 div container to display: flex;